# Using lists as optimization parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimizing a function of many coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4002/minimizing-a-function-of-many-coordinates)

Suppose that the function $F[\vec{x}]$ computes a certain polynomial of the elements of the list $\vec{x}$. How can I use `Nminimize` or `FindMinimum` to find the vector $\vec{x}$ which minimizes the function  $F[\vec{x}]$ ?

Edit: I found this question [Minimizing a function of many coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4002/minimizing-a-function-of-many-coordinates?rq=1)  which asks about the same thing. The answer offered there using arrays, worked for my problem as well.

Comment: What is your actual problem ? Doesn't really `FindMinimum` work ? Have you read documentation pages ?

Comment: @Artes All the examples I found in the documentation uses the elements of $\vec{x}$ explicitly in the call of FindMinimum. Suppose the length of $\vec{x}$ is too big and I want to optimize a generic function over its elements. I don't want to enumerate them one by one in the function call.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but seems like you need `Apply`, e.g. `poly @@ {a, b, c, d, e, f}` yields `poly[a, b, c, d, e, f]`.

Comment: Is the list of variables in `x` available? Please provide a (toy) example of the expression.

Comment: You'll have to create dummy symbols for each element of the list. This is a related question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1957/66

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unanswerable in its present form. Please add sufficient additional detail, especially an example of the kind of input you would feed to `Nminimize` or `FindMinimum`.